# Adding a constraint in while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Trying to solve an equation numerically using a while loop. But I need a physical solution were the answer >0.

Tried putting x>0 both in the loop and in the condition for the while-loop but I still got a negative result. This is just an example code of something similar I have so this probably won't give a negative result but I just want to know how to put in a constraint in the loop.

```
def f(x):
    xold=x
    tol=0.001
    rel=1
    itr=0
    while (rel>tol):
        itr=itr+1
        xnew=2+1/xold
        rel=abs(xnew-xold)/abs(xold)
        xold=xnew
    return xnew
```

Haven't found any information online on how to put constraints in the loop.

Comment: If the loop condition is `x > 0`, then the loop exits when X is negative. That's the entire point of a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think there are some mistakes in your example code. You create `xnew` from `x` (instead of `xold`) and at the end of each iteration you assign `xold` to `xnew` instead of the other way around. The result is that your example is an infinite loop.

Second, to get to the actual problem, let's make an even simpler example:

```py
def f(x):
    xold = x
    while (xold > 0):
        xnew = xold - 1
        #print("old: %s new: %s" % (xold, xnew))
        xold = xnew
    return xnew

result = f(x=3.1)
print(result)
```

This gives a negative number. To see why, let's uncomment the print statement in the function, and check the output. It gives:

```
old: 3.1 new: 2.1
old: 2.1 new: 1.1
old: 1.1 new: 0.10000000000000009
old: 0.10000000000000009 new: -0.8999999999999999
```

The problem is that the loop creates a test case, and if that test case fails, the loop exits. You are returning the test case, intead of the last successful case. Change the return to `xold` and it works.

(Also, note that the code as written will create an error if the input `x` is less than 0, because `xnew` never gets defined in the loop.)

If there's an additional criterion not included in the while statement (often some edge case), you can terminate a loop using a `break` statement inside an `if` clause:

```py
xold = 3.1
while True:
    xnew = xold - 1 
    if xnew <= 0:  # some condition not considered in the while
        break
    xold = xnew
```

Again, this leaves `xold` as the last thing that passed the additional criterion.